# Spring Batch: ItemReader or ItemStream?

Tags: spring-batch

I'm creating a new Spring Batch service.

Reading documentation comes at head some questions:

1. It's not clear to me if it's preferible to use `ItemReader` or `ItemStream`?
2. Can I use Repositories instead of uing `JdbcTemplate`?

I need to import data from mssql to solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. It's not clear to me if it's preferible to use ItemReader or ItemStream?

`ItemStream` is for stateful, restartable item readers/writers. Most built-in readers/writers are restartable (implement `ItemStream`). If you are going to implement a custom item reader/writer and want it to be restartable (meaning you would need to save/load the state from the execution context), you should implement `ItemStream` in addition to `ItemReader`/`ItemWriter` (or implement `ItemStreamReader`/`ItemStreamWriter` which combine both). Otherwise, you can implement only `ItemReader`/`ItemWriter`.

> 2. Can I use Repositories instead of uing JdbcTemplate?

Yes, you can check the [RepositoryItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.html) and [RepositoryItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemWriter.html).

Comment: What do you suggest me? I need to perform a long sql query. I think I don't need to use an repository, simply using a `JdbcTemplate` would be enough. Do you suggest me to use `JdbcCursorItemReader`? Which's the difference between [these readers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#database) and [those ones](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#databaseReaders). I mean, Why doesn't `JdbcCursorItemReader` appear inside `databaseReaders`?

Comment: For long queries, try to use a paging reader as a cursor-based reader will hold the cursor for a long time on the table.