# BigQuery for Spring batch Reader instead of RDMS

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I am new to SpringBatch trying to use Biqquery in spring batch jobs, Itemreader to read the date from BQ table instead of other RDBMS? Trying to build a spring-boot batch application to read from BQ table and write it to a pubsub. Any help is appreciated?

I tried with RDBMS and looking for BigQuery pagination or any other best way to use Spring batch with biquery to read the data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [spring-batch-bigquery](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/main/spring-batch-bigquery) extension.

It provides an item reader and writer for BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.  When I add spring-batch-bigquery - 0.1.0 dependency , I can see only Itemwriter in jar.  Don't see BigQueryQueryItemReader in inside jar. Do I need to use BigQueryQueryItemReader class to build my own logic ?

Comment: The item reader does not seem to be released yet. You can copy the code/license and use it in your project until it is released.

Comment: Queryconfig added "select * from table", it is fetching all table data ,not sure how spring-batch Jdbc/FlatFileReader are reading data line by line.( Internal spring-batch logic) 
-My requirement, I have Biqquery table which holds bulk data. My spring batch has to read the biqquery table data  one by one and send to Webservice as chunk ( for my understanding I am able to achieve these functionality with File reader  and writer), if I add select * from in query reader , it is fetching complete table data, not sure how to read one by one in itemReader through Batch Process  like FlatFileprocess

Comment: the jdbc reader opens a cursor on the table and reads one item at a time from the returned `ResultSet`. The flat file item reader uses a buffered reader behind the scene and streams data one line at a time from the input file. check the code if you need more details on how these readers are implemented.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud , I was able to read the data using ItemStreamReader and  having @stepscope  based on your other SO solutions(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858351/spring-batch-itemreader-or-itemstream) with BIqQuery pagination - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-pagination concept. I can use the Biqquery extension once it officially released.